# LU decomposition of a specific Vandermonde matrix

Tags: binomial-coefficients, lu-decomposition, integer-sequences

I was playing with some unrelated topic and randomly stumbled into following:

Suppose we have a $4 \times 4$ Vandermonde matrix where $x_i = (0,1,2,3)$

$
V =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & x_0^3 \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 \\
1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & x_2^3 \\
1 & x_3 & x_3^2 & x_3^3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & 8 \\
1 & 3 & 9 & 27 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

If we perform LU decomposition of this matrix we get

$V = LU$

$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & 8 \\
1 & 3 & 9 & 27 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 6
\end{pmatrix}
$

I noticed that L matrix is composed of binomial coefficients (Pascal's triangle) and U is composed of OEIS A019538 Triangle of numbers sequence (https://oeis.org/A019538).

Hopefully someone can explain why does this weird connection between binomial coefficients and Triangle of numbers sequence appear? Does someone know where could I read/explore more about this topic? Thanks.